Flutter don't build after upgrade 3.27.1
I'm developing a personal application in flutter and I upgraded it to 3.24.3.
After that, my project doesn't  build anymore.
flutter doctor -v
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.24.3, on Microsoft Windows [Versione 10.0.22631.4602], locale it-IT)
    • Flutter version 3.24.3 on channel stable at C:\dev\flutter
    • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
    • Framework revision 2663184aa7 (3 months ago), 2024-09-11 16:27:48 -0500
    • Engine revision 36335019a8
    • Dart version 3.5.3
    • DevTools version 2.37.3

[√] Windows Version (Installed version of Windows is version 10 or higher)

[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 35.0.0)
    • Android SDK at C:\Users\myUser\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk
    • Platform android-35, build-tools 35.0.0
    • Java binary at: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jbr\bin\java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 21.0.3+-12282718-b509.11)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[√] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe

[√] Visual Studio - develop Windows apps (Visual Studio Community 2022 17.11.5)
    • Visual Studio at C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community
    • Visual Studio Community 2022 version 17.11.35327.3
    • Windows 10 SDK version 10.0.22621.0

[√] Android Studio (version 2024.2)
    • Android Studio at C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • android-studio-dir = C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 21.0.3+-12282718-b509.11)

[√] VS Code, 64-bit edition (version 1.96.2)
    • VS Code at C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code
    • Flutter extension version 3.102.0

[√] Connected device (3 available)
    • Windows (desktop) • windows • windows-x64    • Microsoft Windows [Versione 10.0.22631.4602]
    • Chrome (web)      • chrome  • web-javascript • Google Chrome 131.0.6778.205
    • Edge (web)        • edge    • web-javascript • Microsoft Edge 131.0.2903.112

[√] Network resources
    • All expected network resources are available.

• No issues found!

Creating a new project for test, I can see that adding only some packages, it works; adding all my package needed it doesn't work.
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.8
  http: ^1.2.2
  googleapis: ^13.2.0
  json_annotation: ^4.9.0
  #google_maps_flutter: ^2.10.0
  #location: ^7.0.1
  #uuid: ^4.5.1
  ##google_fonts: ^6.2.1
  #flutter_plugin_android_lifecycle: ^2.0.24
  #image: ^4.5.1
  #google_maps_flutter_platform_interface: ^2.9.5
  #google_maps_flutter_android: ^2.14.11
  flutter_svg: ^2.0.16
  flutter_bloc: ^8.1.6

decommenting 'google_maps_flutter' package, it doesn't build.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':flutter_plugin_android_lifecycle:androidJdkImage'.
  > Failed to transform core-for-system-modules.jar to match attributes {artifactType=_internal_android_jdk_image, org.gradle.libraryelements=jar, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
     > Execution failed for JdkImageTransform: C:\Users\myUser\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platforms\android-34\core-for-system-modules.jar.
        > Error while executing process C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jbr\bin\jlink.exe with arguments {--module-path C:\Users\myUser\.gradle\caches\transforms-3\4a46fc89ed5f9adfe3afebf74eb8bfeb\transformed\output\temp\jmod --add-modules java.base --output C:\Users\myUser\.gradle\caches\transforms-3\4a46fc89ed5f9adfe3afebf74eb8bfeb\transformed\output\jdkImage --disable-plugin system-modules} ```

Thanks


Have you tried to clear and repair caches?

If you give more details about android or ios configuration details it would be better. And also you can check java version as well

My problem solved by this command: flutter create .
